# Laravel cannot find stylesheets and nor can I

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm very new to Laravel and I'm following a tutorial to use the authentication feature. This works fine, however it is unable to find my scripts and stylesheets. I haven't made any new ones nor have I touched the stylesheet link in app.blade.php, so I have no clue why it is throwing this error.

Code:

```
   <link href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Error:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/css/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

When I go to locahost/css/app.css I get a 404 error. The same error is occurring with app.js. I haven't changed anything about the file structure and it was all generated with `composer create-project laravel/laravel`

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running `npm run watch` with browser sync? You'll need to do that to access your app from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn't include any CSS files by default. You need to create one yourself and put it to `/public/` directory, so in your case that would be `/public/css/app.css`.

Comment: but in this video: https://youtu.be/bkyjiXSx6WE he doesn't add any stylesheets and it's already styled?

Comment: That's because the Welcome template (`/resources/views/welcome.blade.php`) contains a `<style>` section.

Comment: That's generated by `php artisan make:auth`. I don't recommend using that for authentication, unless you are fine with out-of-the-box feature that you can't fully customize.

Answer (score 0):

Does localhost point to `public` in your project? Usually you would have to open `http://localhost/public`

Per default, `URL::asset('css/app.css')` expects a css file at `/public/css/app.css` -- for your setup (serving throught `php artisan serve`, I suppose?), that would be `http://localhost:8000/public/css/app.css`.

Anyway: If there is no stylesheet, just create one. There is tons of ways how to do it, depending on your needs. Creating one manually for one, but for complex sites think about using laravel mix for compilation. Or anything other way!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your style exists at public/css directory, then try this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}} type="text/css"/>
```

if the file doesn't exist, create that and try again.

I hope this can help you.